# Trim last 4 characters from string?

Tags: vb.net

How can I trim MyString to be MyStr?

Thanks, google failed again :(

Answer (score 31):

```
YourString.Left(YourString.Length-4)
```

or:

```
YourString.Substring(0,YourString.Length-4)
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a left function in vb.net 2008? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Or: YourString.Substring(0,YourString.Length-4)

Comment: @Jenna: I'ts in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace

Answer (score 7):

c#

```
string str = "MyString";
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 3));
```

vb.net

```
dim str as string = "MyString"
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(0, str.Length - 3))
```

vb.net (with VB6 style functions)

```
dim str as string = "MyString"
Console.WriteLine(Mid(str, 1, len(str) - 3))
```

Answer (score 7):

Rob's answer is mostly correct but the SubString solution will fail whenever the string has less than 4 characters in it.  If the length goes past the end of the string an exception will be thrown.  The following fixes that issue

```
Public Function TrimRight4Characters(ByVal str As String) As String
  If 4 > str.Length Then
    return str.SubString(4, str.Length-4)
  Else
    return str
  End if
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used in my program (VB.NET):

```
    Public Function TrimStr(str As String, charsToRemove As String)
        If str.EndsWith(charsToRemove) Then
            Return str.Substring(0, str.Length - charsToRemove.Length)
        Else
            Return str
        End If
    End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim myStr As String = "hello world"
myStr = TrimStr(myStr, " world")
```

This is my first answer. Hope it helps someone. Feel free to downvote if you don't like this answer.